# Browse for Folder/File dialog from a WPF app on Windows Server Core

Tags: c#, winapi, notepad, server-core, windows-server-2019

I want to be able to browse for folders and file in a WPF app that is running on Windows Server Core.

The default way, using FolderBrowserDialog shows the dialog but the main display panel, selecting folders, is not showing. I've used SHBrowseForFolder too but the same result appears.

I know that windows core by default was not going to support this feature but I figured out that Notepad application is using an open file dialog which is working fine in that OS.
Is it using any other API that I am not aware of? Or it has implemented its own open file dialog and I have to do the same?

Comment: Notepad does not browse for folders.

Comment: Notepad uses open/save dialogs, SHBrowseForFolder is a different dialog.